# Crash with NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, crash-reports

I am getting an occasional crash report from users (which I'm unable to reproduce myself); it's something to do with NSManagedObjectContext `refreshObject`. The crash message is

> "An NSManagedObjectContext cannot refresh objects in other contexts"

The code where it crashes is here:

```
dispatch_async(self.filterMainQueue, ^{
    NSArray *items = [Person getAllNonPrivatePersonsWithContext: self.backgroundContextImage];

    if (items.count) {

        for (Person *person in items) {

                [self.backgroundContextImage performBlockAndWait: ^{
                    [person loadContactReferenceAndImage];

                    // crashes here
                    [self.backgroundContextImage refreshObject: person mergeChanges:NO];
                }];
        }               
    }
});

+ (NSArray *) getAllNonPrivatePersonsWithContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) context{

    __block NSArray *items = nil;

    [context performBlockAndWait: ^{
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext: context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        //[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize: 500];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"isContactPrivate == FALSE"]];
        [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults: FALSE];
        [fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges: FALSE];

        NSError *error = nil;
        items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    }];
    return items;
}
```

I'm not quite sure why this is crashing. The `backgroundContextImage` is created using `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, and I make sure I'm using `performBlockAndWait` when fetching and accessing the managed objects with that context. The `filterMainQueue` is a serial queue, to help with doing this work in a background thread instead of the main thread.

The crash report looks like this:

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x197fb7140
Crashed Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObjectContext cannot refresh objects in other contexts.'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x0000000182a98f48 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x000000019764bf80 objc_exception_throw + 52
2   CoreData                             0x0000000182786898 -[NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject:mergeChanges:] + 1320
3   CJournal                             0x00000001001729c4 __75-[ContactsSyncController loadContactImagesAndLinksWithPermissionWithBlock:]_block_invoke_2 (ContactsSyncController.m:102)
4   CoreData                             0x00000001827dc900 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 192
5   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000197e696a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000197e74954 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 96
7   CoreData                             0x00000001827dc7e8 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 248
8   CJournal                             0x00000001001728bc __75-[ContactsSyncController loadContactImagesAndLinksWithPermissionWithBlock:]_block_invoke (ContactsSyncController.m:97)
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000197e696e8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000197e696a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000197e756ec _dispatch_queue_drain + 860
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000197e6d1ac _dispatch_queue_invoke + 460
13  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000197e696a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
14  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000197e77b40 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2136
15  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000197e772dc _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000019807d470 _pthread_wqthread + 1088
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000019807d020 start_wqthread + 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your person object reference any other CoreData objects? Your instance of person looks pretty safe, but has it become attached to anything in a different context somehow?

Comment: No, don't think so ... there are relationships from Person but they should load as faults in this context.  I'll look more to confirm. But my hunch is that another process is potentially resetting the persistent store (and with it, the main managed object context). Would that potentially explain the problem?

Comment: Thanks. How should I amend my code to take this into account? Considering that the main code above is running in a background queue somewhere, and the persistent store is changed underneath it ... how do I prevent the `refreshObject` from crashing?

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem ... the issue was that under special circumstances, something else in the app would replace the persistentStore and reset the managedObjectContext, and even though the `loadContactReferenceAndImage` and `refreshObject` calls are both within a `performBlockAndWait`, the `backgroundContextImage` is replaced in the middle of this. A little unexpected, because I thought the block would be an atomic operation, but there might be something I'm misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, under special circumstances, something else in the app would replace the persistentStore and reset the managedObjectContext, and even though the loadContactReferenceAndImage and refreshObject calls are both within a performBlockAndWait. The solution I came up with was to confirm if the `managedObjectContext` was the same, and only then refresh the object:

```
       [self.backgroundContextImage performBlockAndWait: ^{
              [person loadContactReferenceAndImage];

              // MOC could have been updated by another thread
              if (person.managedObjectContext == self.backgroundContextImage) {
                  [self.backgroundContextImage refreshObject: person mergeChanges:NO];
              }

       }];
```